# Movieclip stops rotating after it's Box2D Body

Tags: actionscript-3, box2d

I have made a Car Game using Box2D [in Flash] and I have one remaining bug, which I cannot fix. I added graphics and put them on top of the Box2D body. Everything went as good as expected, but after X rotations the movie clips for the car-wheels, stop spinning. I do something like this `wheelSprite.rotation = wheelBody.GetAngle() * 180 / Math.PI`. I ran a separate program and I saw that, if you do `X.rotation += variable` and you increase the variable every frame, after ~30 000 (value of variable) the MovieClip stops rotating, so I reset it to 0 after ~28 000. What do I do? The `wheelBody.GetAngle()` keeps going up, and I need it to make it look real. How do I reset it?

Answer (score 4):

I faced this problem some time ago. The solution was:

```
rotation = newRotation % 2*Math.PI;
```

Which means that rotation must be between 0 and 360 degrees (0 - 2*PI).

Answer (score 2):

Remainder solve this issue:

```
yourMC.rotation = (yourMCbody.GetAngle() * 180 / Math.PI) % 360;
```

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/operators.html#modulo

Answer (score 0):

Can't you use the SetAngle() function to set the angle to an equivalent angle?

ie: If the angle rotates over 360 degrees, set it back to 0?

Answer (score 0):

The Box2D manual specifies that the rotation of bodies is unbounded and may get big after awhile and that you can you can reset it using `SetAngle`.

I use a while loop to calculate the normalized angle (you can apparently call modulo with a floating point operand but I don't know if that is bad for performance).  This code normalizes the angle to `0 <= angle < 2pi` but I've seen angles sometimes normalized to `-pi <= angle < pi` as well.

```
const 2PI:Number = Math.PI * 2;
var rotation:Number = wheelBody.GetAngle();
// normalize angle
while(rotation >= 2PI)
    rotation -= 2PI;
while(rotation < 0)
    rotation += 2PI;
// store the normalized angle back into Box2D body so it doesn't overflow (optional)
wheelBody.SetAngle(rotation);
// convert to degrees and set rotation of flash sprite
wheelSprite.rotation = rotation * 180 / Math.PI;
```

I haven't collected the code into a function but it would be easy to do so.